# forms.SplitDateTimeField in two table td on the template

Tags: django, datetime, split, element

I've a datefield that I split in two elements on a form as follow :

```
class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    date = forms.SplitDateTimeField(input_time_formats=['%H:%M'], input_date_formats=['%d.%m.%Y'])
```

And on the **init** :

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['date'].widget.widgets[0].attrs.update({'class' : 'datepicker'}) #assign the class date to the datefield
    self.fields['date'].widget.widgets[1].attrs.update({'class' : 'timepicker'}) #assign the class date to the datefield
```

On my template, I try as much as possible to not making custom table, but to used the auto generated one done by django as follow :

```
<form id="form_invoice_add">
{% csrf_token %}
<table class="table">
    {{ form.as_table }}
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the two splited field are generated on the same line.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="id_date_0">Date&nbsp;:</label></th>
            <td><input class="datepicker" id="id_date_0" name="date_0" type="text" value="2015-10-08"><input class="timepicker" id="id_date_1" name="date_1" type="text" value="18:29:43"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I should have the second field (timefield) on another td as follow. How should I do it without modifying my auto generated table by django?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="id_date_0">Date&nbsp;:</label></th>
        <td><input class="datepicker" id="id_date_0" name="date_0" type="text" value="2015-10-08"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="id_date_0">Date&nbsp;:</label></th>
        <td><input class="timepicker" id="id_date_1" name="date_1" type="text" value="18:29:43"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Does that mean I should change my form to something like this :

```
class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
separate_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M'])
separate_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y'])

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(InvoiceForm, self).clean()
    self.cleaned_data['date'] = datetime.datetime.combine(self.cleaned_data['separate_date'], self.cleaned_data['separate_time'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have a lot of options to achieve your goal. 
What I see is that you can to have actually two separate fields: date and time with appropriate widgets, and a result datetime field which won't be displayed in template and will be filled in form's clean method.